# Error: could not find function "forceAndCall" - outdated base package?

Tags: r

I would like to apply the function 'fit.tcopula' from the package 'QRM' - Quantitative Risk Management and get the following error message:

```
fit.tcopula(Udata, method = 'Kendall')
Error: could not find function "forceAndCall"
```

Since I have applied the 'Udata' to different copulas from the package 'copula' already - and it worked fine - I assume the input is not an issue.
To my understanding 'forceAndCall' is part of the base package. I use the R version 3.1.3.
According to the documentation the QRM package depends R(>=3.0.1), so my version should be OK. However, listing all functions of my base package with

```
library(help = 'base')
```

reveals that the forceAndCall-Function is not there. What would the remedy be? Installing R version 3.2.1? 
The reason I ask and not just do it is that I do not possess admin rights for my PC and therefore would be happy to get an opinion beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the question though I already have the answer as it might be interesting to others.
Upgrading to R version 3.2.1 is the/one solution to the problem!